# Redis-Objects in rails saves as String, not array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, marshalling, redis-objects

I am using the [redis-objects](https://github.com/nateware/redis-objects) gem to store simple info

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Redis::Objects
  hash_key :user_purchases, :marshal => true, :global => true  # "hash" is taken by Ruby

  def self.add_user_end(fb_id,item_id)
    if self.user_purchases[fb_id]
      a = Array.new
      a << candidate_id 
      self.user_purchases[fb_id] = a
    else
      new_a = self.user_purchases[fb_id]
      new_a << item_id
      self.user_purchases[fb_id] = new_a
    end
  end
end
```

I'm creating a method to collect user_purchases as a hasy_key, keyed by a users fb id. I would imply like to see a collection of ids when I use Purchase.user_purchases["2"] => [1,23,563,2]

I am running into a problem with Redis::Object where I can only save this as a string: Why?

```
1.9.3-p125 :050 > Purchase.user_purchases["6"].class
 => String 
1.9.3-p125 :051 > Purchase.user_purchases["6"]
 => "\u0004\b[\u0006I\"\v543555\u0006:\u0006ET"
```

Answer:

My Initialization file was missing require 'redis/list'

```
require 'redis'
require 'redis/objects'
require 'redis/hash_key'
require 'redis/list'

Redis.current = Redis.new(:host => '127.0.0.1', :port => 6379)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Initialization file was missing require 'redis/list'

```
require 'redis'
require 'redis/objects'
require 'redis/hash_key'
require 'redis/list'

Redis.current = Redis.new(:host => '127.0.0.1', :port => 6379)
```